How to prevent shallow copying of common fields between entity and DTO in a mapper?
I'm currently using a mapper and encountering an issue.
Both Entity and Dto have a common field object called option. As a result, the mapping logic is automatically generated like this:
@Override
public Dto toDto(Entity entity) {
    ...
    dto.setOption(entity.getOption());
    ...
    return Dto.build();
}

For your information, the attached code is the code made by mapstruct and cannot be modified by the developer directly
The problem is that when I convert the Entity to Dto, the option field is shallowly copied. So when I call dto.getOption().setName("change!"), it actually triggers dirty checking and reflects the change in the original entity.
To fundamentally solve this issue, do I need to separate the option in Entity and Dto? I'm a bit hesitant because they are essentially identical objects.
I tried using a mapper to convert the entity to a DTO. The mapping works, but since the option field is shallow copied, any modifications to Dto's option object also affect the original entity.
I was expecting Dto to be independent of Entity, so that changes made to Dto's option wouldn't trigger dirty checking on the entity. I want to find a solution that wouldn't require separating the option object into two distinct instances if possible, as they are essentially the same.

I think the dirty checking problem is fixed simply when you make a new instance for option instead using an orginal one. e.g. new Option(entity.getOption().name()).

And I think that seperation is nice between entity and dto. Dto is for presentaiton layers. Entity is for persistent layers. In some cases, presentation layers are not interested in some fields in Entity.

Consider using immutable classes used like primitive types, String, LocalDate, record instances. This has the best operational behavior. Why costly copy when you probably mostly do not change an object. Here maybe StandardOpenOption might be an example.
